# How to use RestSharp to get a json file inside of a github repo

Tags: c#, restsharp

I need to get a json file from github using RestSharp. I'm coding in C#.

I have tried it like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using RestSharp.Extensions;

namespace OurOSBasic.O_OS_Kernel.ACK
{
    internal class Commands
    {
        public string Command { get; set; }
        public short Response { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Command,20}: {Response} contributions";
        }
    }


    class CommandParser
    {
        private static System.Text.Json.JsonElement root;
        private static System.Text.Json.JsonElement.ArrayEnumerator elems;

        public static async void CommandParserFunc()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://github.com");

            var request = new RestRequest("OurWorldMetaverse/OurOSBasic/blob/main/O_OS-Kernel/ACK/Resources/ACKCommands.json", Method.Get);
            // Add HTTP headers
            request.AddHeader("User-Agent", "Nothing");

            // Execute the request and automatically deserialize the result.
            var contributors = client.ExecuteAsync<List<Commands>>(request);
            Console.Write(contributors.Result.Data);


        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to make a desktop application that simulates an OS. This code is me trying to make a CommandParser for the console of it.

To no avail. Any help means a lot.

Comment: You are getting the web page. You need to get a link to the raw JSON file content and read that instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to understand what are you trying to do, but your code has quite a few issues.

- You are reading `https://github.com/OurWorldMetaverse/OurOSBasic/blob/main/O_OS-Kernel/ACK/Resources/ACKCommands.json` which is not a JSON file, it's a web page.
- The raw JSON file is available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OurWorldMetaverse/OurOSBasic/main/O_OS-Kernel/ACK/Resources/ACKCommands.json
- The file itself contains this:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "**/bin",
    "**/bower_components",
    "**/jspm_packages",
    "**/node_modules",
    "**/obj",
    "**/platforms"
  ],
  "Commands": {
    "ping": "pong",
    "isaiah": "Isaiah is the Head of 3D Modeling at OurWorld",
    "clear": "Clearning Console...",
    "duggo": "Duggoooo!",
    "aidyn": "Have a kermit",
    "magnet": "AA A MAGNET NOOO!",
    "upshot": "ITS RAINING DOLLA BILLS",
    "FakeMathew": "Need to be incognito?"
  }
}
```

and it has little to nothing to do with your `Commands` class, as first the `Commands` collection is a map, second, it is a property, not the root element, and third, it has no `short` values there at all, all the values are strings.

- You are using `async void` that is not something anyone should be doing.
- You are getting `.Result` instead of awaiting the call

Here is the code that works, but I think you'd benefit from learning some basics of C# first.

```
using RestSharp;

var client = new RestClient("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/");
var response = await client.GetJsonAsync<Response>("OurWorldMetaverse/OurOSBasic/main/O_OS-Kernel/ACK/Resources/ACKCommands.json");
Console.WriteLine(response!.Commands["ping"]);

class Commands : Dictionary<string, string>{}

class Response {
    public Commands? Commands { get; set; }
}
```